# How to include glossary directly in TeX file?

Tags: glossaries

The glossaries package uses external files (especially a `.gls` file) to build the glossary, e.g. when building the following example. Is there a way to include the content of such a file directly into the TeX file? Then it would not be necessary to use `makeglossaries` or to provide the `.gls` file, e.g. when submitting the TeX file to a journal.

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{glossaries}
\makeglossaries

\newglossaryentry{eta}{name=\ensuremath{\eta},description={eta}}
\newglossaryentry{psi}{name=\ensuremath{\psi},description={psi}}

\begin{document}
    \glsaddall
    \printglossary
\end{document}
```

Directly adding the content of the file to the TeX file gives

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \glossarytitle
```

By the way: There is no need to update references or anything else. I just need the layout and the entries.

Comment: There is also `\makenoidxglossaries` and `\printnoidxglossaries`, which should do, what you want: Omitting `makeglossaries` step

Comment: That solves my problem, thanks a lot! For the given MWE it gives "Improper alphabetic constant" but for my actual manuscript it works. If you add this as an answer I can accept it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`\printglossary` doesn't just input the glossary file but performs quite a bit of setup first, which is why you can't simply replace it with `\input`.

Basically, if you don't want to use an external application, then:

1. If you want all defined entries, don't want number lists and don't need automatic sorting use `\printunsrtglossary` provided by the [`glossaries-extra`](http://ctan.org/pkg/glossaries-extra) extension package.
2. Otherwise use `\makenoidxglossary` and `\printnoidxglossary` (as mentioned by Christian).

Example with the first approach:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage[nogroupskip]{glossaries-extra}

\newglossaryentry{eta}{name=\ensuremath{\eta},description={eta}}
\newglossaryentry{psi}{name=\ensuremath{\psi},description={psi}}

\begin{document}
\printunsrtglossary
\end{document}
```

[image: image of glossary with no number list]

This only requires a single `latex` call as no sorting is performed and there's no check to determine if the entry has been indexed. I've used the `nogroupskip` as there are no logical letter groups in this case.

The above method is different to using the `\makenoidxglossaries` and `\printnoidxglossary` approach, which requires a second run to determine which entries have been indexed. The `noidx` method (denoted [option 1](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/glossaries/glossaries-user.html#option1) in the manual) also tries to sort the entries alphabetically by default and will obtain the sort value from the `name` key if the `sort` key is omitted, but the maths markup (`\ensuremath{\eta}` etc) causes a problem. Example using order of definition (instead of alphabetical ordering):

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage[sort=def,nogroupskip]{glossaries}

\makenoidxglossaries

\newglossaryentry{eta}{name=\ensuremath{\eta},description={eta}}
\newglossaryentry{psi}{name=\ensuremath{\psi},description={psi}}

\begin{document}
\glsaddall

\printnoidxglossary
\end{document}
```

[image: image of glossary with locations]

It is actually possible to add letter groups and location lists with `\printunsrtglossary` but it has to be done manually:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{glossaries-extra}

\glsaddstoragekey{group}{}{\entrygroup}
\glsaddstoragekey{location}{}{\entrylocation}

\glsxtrsetgrouptitle{greek}{Greek Symbols}

\newglossaryentry{eta}{name=\ensuremath{\eta},description={eta},
 group={greek},location={\setentrycounter[]{page}\hyperbf{5}}}
\newglossaryentry{psi}{name=\ensuremath{\psi},description={psi},
 group={greek},location={\setentrycounter[]{page}\hyperit{3}}}

\begin{document}
\printunsrtglossary[style=indexgroup]
\end{document}
```

[image: image of glossary with letter group heading and locations]

Both methods require all entries to be defined before the glossary. The second case requires all entries to be defined in the preamble. The first case may allow document definitions but only with the package option `docdefs=restricted`. In general it's best to put all [document definitions in the preamble](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/glossaries/glossaries-user.html#sec:docdefs).